# SSIS Package with WinSCP SFTP Task - Execute as Proxy/SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis, winscp

I have an SSIS package with below WinSCP SFTP script as execute process task.

```
open <user_name>@<host_name>/ -hostkey="ssh-here"
option transfer binary
get *.csv C:\Users\username\input\
close
exit
```

It runs successfully in Data Tools 2015 but keeps running forever without actually finishing when executed as an SSIS job. I am lost how to debug it as it doesn't even give me an error.

I tried changing package and job to 32-bit environment. I tried using a custom .ini file for WinSCP. Instead of using SQL Server Agent to run the job I also tried using proxy. But nothing. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

SSIS Task:
[image: SSIS Execute Process Task]

example.out file from https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler:

[image: WinSCP batch file output]

Edit: I also tried deploying the project as ispac file. I took the screenshot at 2:45 AM. Execution report-
[image: ispac file execution result]

I am attaching some log that I generated by running the script from cmd. In the end it copied all the files to my desired location.

```
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.639 WinSCP Version 5.17.6 (Build 10516) (OS 10.0.18363 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.639 Configuration: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\WinSCP.ini
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Log level: Normal
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Local account: myusername
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Process ID: 11720
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Command-line: winscp.exe  /script=C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\ftp.txt /log=C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\log1.txt
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.640 Time zone: Current: GMT-5, Standard: GMT-6 (Central Standard Time), DST: GMT-5 (Central Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/8/2020, DST End: 11/1/2020
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Login time: Wednesday, June 17, 2020 2:10:19 AM
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Script: open hostuser@hostaddress/ -hostkey="ssh-here"
< 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Script: In scripting you should not rely on saved sites, use this command instead:
< 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Script: open sftp://hostuser:***@hostaddress/ -hostkey="ssh-here"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Session name: hostuser@hostaddress (Modified site)
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Host name: hostaddress (Port: 22)
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 User name: hostuser (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Tunnel: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Disable Nagle: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Proxy: None
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Send buffer: 262144
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Bypass authentication: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Simple channel: Yes
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Shell: default
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 SFTP Server: default
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Local directory: C:\Users\myusername\Downloads, Remote directory: /home/hostuser, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 DST mode: Unix
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.641 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.642 Looking up host "hostaddress" for SSH connection
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.664 Connecting to hostipaddress port 22
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.729 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.17.6
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.804 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.804 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.808 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2020-06-17 02:10:19.878 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.021 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.021 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.021 ssh-ed25519 <fingerprint>
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.022 Host key matches cached key
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.023 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.023 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.023 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.023 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
! 2020-06-17 02:10:20.085 Using username "hostuser".
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.153 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.153 Using GSSAPI from GSSAPI32.DLL
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.153 Trying gssapi-with-mic...
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.153 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.218 GSSAPI authentication request refused
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.218 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.218 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.218 Using stored password.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.218 Sent password
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.388 Access granted
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.388 Opening main session channel
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.719 Opened main channel
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.783 Started a shell/command
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.783 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.783 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.784 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.784 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 150, Number: -1
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version "1"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Unknown server extension fsync@openssh.com="1"
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 strings are not mandatory
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Changing directory to "/home/hostuser".
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Getting real path for '/home/hostuser'
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.845 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 26, Number: 16
< 2020-06-17 02:10:20.918 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 55, Number: 16
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.919 Real path is '/home/hostuser'
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.919 Trying to open directory "/home/hostuser".
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.919 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 26, Number: 263
< 2020-06-17 02:10:20.976 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 263
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.976 Getting current directory name.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.976 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2020-06-17 02:10:20.976 Script: Active session: [1] hostuser@hostaddress
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.977 Script: option transfer binary
< 2020-06-17 02:10:20.977 Script: transfer        binary    
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.977 Script: get *files.csv C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\
. 2020-06-17 02:10:20.977 Listing directory "/home/hostuser".
> 2020-06-17 02:10:20.977 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 26, Number: 523
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.047 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 523
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.047 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 780
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.130 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 11283, Number: 780
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.130 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 1036
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.192 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 1036
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 Status code: 1
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 1284
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 7-files.csv;-;4053632;2020-06-04T15:03:13.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 41-files.csv;-;4419453;2020-06-11T22:22:19.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 .bashrc;-;231;2020-05-22T17:21:25.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-------;2
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 51-files.csv;-;3927873;2020-06-15T21:52:56.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 16-files.csv;-;4695185;2020-06-11T20:47:44.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 26-files.csv;-;4753794;2020-06-11T21:31:50.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 25-files.csv;-;4772815;2020-06-11T21:29:04.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.193 18-files.csv;-;4591658;2020-06-11T20:55:36.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 21-files.csv;-;4697231;2020-06-11T21:11:29.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 75-files.csv;-;3627263;2020-06-16T14:05:57.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 22-files.csv;-;4772393;2020-06-11T21:14:24.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 56-files.csv;-;3957332;2020-06-16T12:50:29.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 53-files.csv;-;3890471;2020-06-16T12:42:25.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 42-files.csv;-;4468618;2020-06-11T22:24:44.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 39-files.csv;-;4348507;2020-06-11T22:13:49.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 46-files.csv;-;4810788;2020-06-13T11:06:53.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 61-files.csv;-;4001343;2020-06-16T13:07:50.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 40-files.csv;-;4382588;2020-06-11T22:20:03.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 45-files.csv;-;4818957;2020-06-12T11:02:54.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 68-files.csv;-;3742467;2020-06-16T13:38:05.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 62-files.csv;-;3982322;2020-06-16T13:15:19.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 31-files.csv;-;4476997;2020-06-11T21:46:04.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 .bash_history;-;374;2020-06-04T18:26:58.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-------;2
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 17-files.csv;-;4650815;2020-06-11T20:51:48.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 30-files.csv;-;4461579;2020-06-11T21:43:04.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 34-files.csv;-;4456767;2020-06-11T21:55:18.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 80-files.csv;-;3992542;2020-06-16T14:22:52.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 14-files.csv;-;4016294;2020-06-10T11:04:52.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 37-files.csv;-;4350410;2020-06-11T22:04:00.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.194 4-files.csv;-;4055410;2020-06-01T11:06:21.000Z;3;"hostuser" [10069];"mbuftp" [10001];rw-r--r--;0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Copying 81 files/directories to local directory "C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\" - total size: 346,129,549
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: 
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 File: '/home/hostuser/7-files.csv' [2020-06-04T15:03:13.000Z] [4053632]
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Copying "/home/hostuser/7-files.csv" to local directory started.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Opening remote file.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.195 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 50, Number: 1539
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.282 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1284
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.282 Discarding reserved response
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.282 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 1539
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.282 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 1800
< 2020-06-17 02:10:21.345 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 1800
. 2020-06-17 02:10:21.345 Confirming overwriting of file.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:21.346 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 2053
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Status code: 1
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 280 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 41988
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 34053
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 34309
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 34565
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 34821
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 35077
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.230 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 35333
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 35589
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 35845
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 36101
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 36357
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 36613
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 36869
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37125
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37381
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37637
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 37893
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 38149
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 38405
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 38661
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 38917
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 39173
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 39429
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 39685
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 39941
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 40197
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 40453
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 40709
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.231 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 40965
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.329 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 41221
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.337 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 41477
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.407 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 41733
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.407 Preserving timestamp [2020-06-04T15:03:13.000Z]
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Transfer done: '/home/hostuser/7-files.csv' => 'C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\7-files.csv' [4053632]
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 File: '/home/hostuser/73-files.csv' [2020-06-16T13:53:14.000Z] [3626982]
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Copying "/home/hostuser/73-files.csv" to local directory started.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Opening remote file.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 51, Number: 42243
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 41988
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.409 Discarding reserved response
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.478 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 42243
> 2020-06-17 02:10:25.478 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 42504
< 2020-06-17 02:10:25.536 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 42504
. 2020-06-17 02:10:25.537 Confirming overwriting of file.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:25.537 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 42757
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Status code: 1
. 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 254 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 79364
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 71429
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 71685
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 71941
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 72197
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 72453
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 72709
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 72965
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 73221
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 73477
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 73733
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 73989
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 74245
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 74501
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 74757
< 2020-06-17 02:10:29.987 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 75013
< 2020-06-17 02:10:30.070 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 78853
< 2020-06-17 02:10:30.131 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 79109
. 2020-06-17 02:10:30.131 Preserving timestamp [2020-06-16T13:53:14.000Z]
. 2020-06-17 02:10:30.133 Transfer done: '/home/hostuser/73-files.csv' => 'C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\73-files.csv' [3626982]
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 File: '/home/hostuser/4-files.csv' [2020-06-01T11:06:21.000Z] [4055410]
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Copying "/home/hostuser/4-files.csv" to local directory started.
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Checking existence of partially transferred file.
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Opening remote file.
> 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 50, Number: 3401731
< 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 3401476
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.669 Discarding reserved response
< 2020-06-17 02:16:36.726 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 3401731
> 2020-06-17 02:16:36.726 Type: SSH_FXP_FSTAT, Size: 13, Number: 3401992
< 2020-06-17 02:16:36.783 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 3401992
. 2020-06-17 02:16:36.783 Confirming overwriting of file.
> 2020-06-17 02:16:36.784 Type: SSH_FXP_READ, Size: 25, Number: 3402245
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Status code: 1
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 280 skipped SSH_FXP_WRITE, SSH_FXP_READ, SSH_FXP_DATA and SSH_FXP_STATUS packets.
> 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 3442180
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3434245
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3436293
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3436549
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3436805
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3437061
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3437317
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3437573
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3437829
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3438085
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3438341
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3438597
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3438853
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3439109
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3439365
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3439621
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3439877
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3440133
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3440389
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3440645
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3440901
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3441157
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.685 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3441413
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.748 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3441669
< 2020-06-17 02:16:39.805 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 3441925
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.805 Preserving timestamp [2020-06-01T11:06:21.000Z]
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.808 Transfer done: '/home/hostuser/4-files.csv' => 'C:\Users\myusername\SSIS\4-files.csv' [4055410]
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.808 Copying finished: Transferred: 346,129,549, Elapsed: 0:06:18, CPS: 1,216,365/s
> 2020-06-17 02:16:39.808 Script: close
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.808 Closing connection.
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.808 Sending special code: 1
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.866 Session sent command exit status 0
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.866 Main session channel closed
. 2020-06-17 02:16:39.866 All channels closed
```

Comment: Has the account that is being proxied ever logged into the server the package is running on and has it added the keys to it's keychain or whatever jiggery pokery you have to do the first time you set up WinSCP with a new host?

Comment: Proxy account has my credentials which I use on daily basis to login to the server which is now running the SSIS package.

Comment: Just so we're clear, you have physically logged on to the sever and and performed the  one-time setup task has been. You can run the package on the server via dtexec just fine? In my experience, the key management step represents 99.99999999999% of all the trouble people have with SSIS packages and sftp

Comment: Yes, I physically logged on to the server with my credentials(same ones in proxy) and I can run the package using VS DT just fine. I am able to run the exact same script from command line and also connect to remote server using WinSCP GUI. However, I am not sure about key setup. I did not perform any such step. What exactly is that?

Comment: Is that a log from SSIS for a task that appears to *"keep running forever"*? There's no indication for that in the log. How do you run WinSCP exactly from SSIS?

Comment: no, there is no specific log to show that "running forever" job. The above image can serve as proof to certain extent, I believe. And the verbose log is to show my script runs fine from cmd. Running of WinSCP from SSIS is in this-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHoYhwG2iI

Comment: Sorry, but we are not going to watch 6 minutes long video. We need your question to include [mcve].

Comment: I used 'Execute Process Task' in SSIS(attached image). This has Executable as 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe' and Arguments as '/ini=C:\Users\username\SSIS\WinSCP.ini /script=C:\Users\username\SSIS\ftp.txt'

Comment: Try wrapping WinSCP to a batch file to improve debugging possibilities. See this guide: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler, particularly the section *"Inspecting Output Log"*.

Comment: Martin. I executed the batch script from your link and when executed from cmd, it created example.out file (attached image in question). When I tried using winscp.com to call the batch file, it gave me 'no session' as output.

Comment: ??? WinSCP cannot run the batch file. The batch file runs WinSCP. Run the batch file from SSIS.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Executed the batch file from SSIS and received the same log and out files that I posted above. No error.

Comment: Does you batch file have `echo WinSCP done`? Do you see that message in the output log?